# Handling Content property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm currently facing huge problem i.e I'm showing Image and some text in a image the problem is when I change content property of button from code, my image disappears and only assigned text is shown, I wan to retain image and just wann change the text, Any suggetions how to handle it

```
<Button x:Name="btnPrescan" Margin="8" Grid.Column="2" Click="btnPrescan_Click">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Image Source="Icons\Scan_Start_Icon.png" Height="14" Width="23"/>
         <TextBlock x:Name="tbButtonText"  Text="    Prescan"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

and button looks something like this

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the text to a backing property on your UserControl:

```
<Button x:Name="btnPrescan" Margin="8" Grid.Column="2" Click="btnPrescan_Click">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Image Source="Icons\Scan_Start_Icon.png" Height="14" Width="23"/>
         <!-- assumes DataContext is set appropriately -->
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding ButtonText}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Then just change the backing property:

```
this.ButtonText = "New button text";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this way,

```
((TextBlock)btnPrescan.GetTemplatedChild("tbButtonText")).Text = "Your Text"
```